# how to set a bounce back email address on PHP Pear Mail Queue?

Tags: php, pear

I'm using PHP Pear Mail Queue to send queued emails, but I can't get the bounce back (undelivered) emails to work. I'm using Mail_mime to create headers, looks something like that:

```
        $hdrs = array(
            "From"        => EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS, 
            "Reply-To"    => EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS, 
            "Return-Path" => EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
            "To"          => $recipient, 
            "Subject"     => $this->NewsletterTitle
        );
```

Note, that even though Return-Path is defined, I don't get bounce backs to that email address. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem - it was Pear issue afterall, all I did is update it, problem solved.